# Problems with RASP lemmatizer in GATE (using Mac)

Tags: plugins, gate, lemmatization

I am analysing novels in English to extract relevant linguistic information from them. To this end, I am using GATE and need a lemmatizer, so I was trying to use the RASP tool with one of the example pipelines that are suggested: 
1) RegEx Sentence Splitter
2) RAPS2 Tokenizer
3) RASP2 POS Tagger
4) RASP 2 Morphological Analyser
5) RASP2 Parser.

I am using a desktop Mac (OS X 10.9.4) and the latest version of GATE. When I load the RegEx Sentence Splitter in the "Processing Resources" of GATE, I have no problem. But then, when I try loading the first RAPS tool, RAPS2 Tokenizer, I get an error message saying "gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException: java.lang.Exception: Executable /Applications/gate-8.0-build4825-ALL/plugins/Parser_RASP/resources/tokenise/token.x86_64_mac os x does not exist
    at com.digitalpebble.rasp2.token.RASPTokenizer.init(RASPTokenizer.java:71)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:432)
    at gate.gui.NewResourceDialog$4.run(NewResourceDialog.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Executable /Applications/gate-8.0-build4825-ALL/plugins/Parser_RASP/resources/tokenise/token.x86_64_mac os x does not exist"

and the RASP2 Tokenizer does not get loaded into GATE.

Can you tell me why this is? What is happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

RASP itself is a native (non-Java) program.  The GATE plugin includes a selection of different versions of the RASP binary compiled for specific platforms, and tries to select the appropriate one automatically by constructing a file name from the architecture and operating system name of the host platform.

There isn't a `.x86_64_mac os x` variant, but 64-bit Mac OS can run 32-bit binaries.  The `.ix86_darwin` version works for me on OS X (10.10) so you should be able to make it work by making a copy of or a link to the `token.ix86_darwin` file named `token.x86_64_mac os x` (including the spaces).  In a Terminal:

```
cd /Applications/gate-8.0-build4825-ALL/plugins/Parser_RASP/resources/tokenise
ln -s 'token.ix86_darwin' 'token.x86_64_mac os x'
```